# Custom archives page by month and year - nesting problem

Tags: php, archives

I'm attempting to add a custom archives page within wordpress, outputting a complete list of archives by year and month. The code below works, more or less, but a html validator outputs errors saying their are ul elements that are unclosed.

Despite trying numerous variations and playing around with the code for hours, I cannot figure out why the ul and li nesting is buggy.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong? (The code is for use in the Genesis framework for wordpress).

```
add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'custom_page_archive_content' );
function custom_page_archive_content() {

    global $post;
    echo '<ul class="archives">';
        $lastposts = get_posts('numberposts=-1');
        $year = '';
        $month = '';
        foreach($lastposts as $post) :
            setup_postdata($post);

            if(ucfirst(get_the_time('F')) != $month && $month != ''){
                echo '</ul></li><!-- /monthly-archives -->';
            }
            if(get_the_time('Y') != $year && $year != ''){
                echo '</ul></li>';
            }
            if(get_the_time('Y') != $year){
                $year = get_the_time('Y');
                echo '<li><h2>' . $year . '</h2><ul class="monthly-archives">';
            }
            if(ucfirst(get_the_time('F')) != $month){
                $month = ucfirst(get_the_time('F'));
                echo '<li><h3>' . $month . '</h3><ul>';
            }
        ?>
            <li>
                <span class="the_date"><?php the_time('d') ?>:</span>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <span class="comments-number"><?php comments_number('(0)','(1)','(%)'); ?></span>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul><!-- /archives -->
        <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much more work, I developed a solution that outputs archives by year, month and day while minimising database calls. Posting it here for others to use:

```
//* Add custom archives below entry content
add_action( 'genesis_entry_content', 'custom_archives_page_content' );
function custom_archives_page_content() {

global $post;

// set post arguments
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'orderby'       => 'post_date',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
);

// get posts from wordpress
$posts = get_posts($args);

// setup an associative array with three levels, for every year, month and posts
$years = array();

foreach ($posts as $post) {

    $year  = mysql2date('Y', $post->post_date);
    $month = mysql2date('F', $post->post_date);

    // specify the position of the current post
    $years[$year][$month][] = $post;
}

// begin the archives ?>

<ul class="yearly-archives">

<?php foreach ($years as $year => $months) : // shows the years ?>

    <li><h2><?php echo $year ?></h2><ul class="monthly-archives">

    <?php foreach ($months as $month => $posts ) : // shows the months ?>

        <li><h3><?php printf("%s (%d)", $month, count($months[$month])) ?></h3><ul class="daily-archives">

        <?php foreach($posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); // shows the posts ?>

            <li>
            <span class="date"><?php the_time('d') ?>:</span>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <span class="comments-number"><?php comments_number('(0)','(1)','(%)'); ?></span>
            </li>

        <?php endforeach; // ends foreach for $posts ?>
        </ul><!-- /daily-archives --></li>

    <?php endforeach; // ends foreach for $months ?>
    </ul><!-- /monthly-archives --></li> 

<?php endforeach; // ends foreach for $years ?>
</ul><!-- /yearly-archives -->
<?php
}
```

Props to [davidmh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16378889/wordpress-archive-list-with-year-month-days-posts-and-comment-counts) and [mikos](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-all-posts-on-a-page-split-them-by-year).